# SQL - Losing columns after a left join

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join, cross-join

Here's what I have in DB Fiddle (using PostgreSQL v9.6):

A sample table:

```
CREATE TABLE sample_table (
  seller_id varchar(255),
  week varchar(255),
  week_end  timestamp,
  year  integer,
  product_id varchar(255),
  num_sold  integer,
  dollars_sold  integer
);
```

Populated with fake data:

```
INSERT INTO sample_table (seller_id, week, week_end, year, product_id, num_sold, dollars_sold)
VALUES ('12345A', '01/01/2020 - 01/07/2020', '01/07/2020', 2020, '1A', 1, 5),
       ('12345A', '01/08/2020 - 01/14/2020', '01/14/2020', 2020, '1A', 2, 10),
       ('12345A', '01/15/2020 - 01/21/2020', '01/21/2020', 2020, '1A', 3, 15),
       ('12345B', '01/01/2020 - 01/07/2020', '01/07/2020', 2020, '1A', 2, 10),
       ('12345B', '01/08/2020 - 01/14/2020', '01/14/2020', 2020, '1A', 4, 20),
       ('12345B', '01/15/2020 - 01/21/2020', '01/21/2020', 2020, '1A', 6, 30),
       ('12345C', '01/01/2020 - 01/07/2020', '01/07/2020', 2020, '1A', 1, 5),
       ('12345C', '01/08/2020 - 01/14/2020', '01/14/2020', 2020, '1A', 2, 10),
       ('12345C', '01/15/2020 - 01/21/2020', '01/21/2020', 2020, '1A', 3, 15),
       ('12345D', '01/01/2020 - 01/07/2020', '01/07/2020', 2020, '1A', 5, 25),
       ('12345D', '01/08/2020 - 01/14/2020', '01/14/2020', 2020, '1A', 10, 50),
       ('12345D', '01/15/2020 - 01/21/2020', '01/21/2020', 2020, '1A', 15, 75),
       ('12345E', '01/01/2020 - 01/07/2020', '01/07/2020', 2020, '1A', 3, 15),
       ('12345E', '01/08/2020 - 01/14/2020', '01/14/2020', 2020, '1A', 6, 30),
       ('12345E', '01/15/2020 - 01/21/2020', '01/21/2020', 2020, '1A', 9, 45);
```

And my query:

```
SELECT a.* FROM (SELECT     x.week_end, 
           x.week, 
           x.year, 
           y.product_id, 
           z.seller_id 
FROM       ( 
                           SELECT DISTINCT week_end, 
                                           year, 
                                           week 
                           FROM            sample_table) x 
CROSS JOIN 
           ( 
                           SELECT DISTINCT product_id 
                           FROM            sample_table) y 
CROSS JOIN 
           ( 
                           SELECT DISTINCT seller_id 
                           FROM            sample_table) z) AS a
LEFT JOIN sample_table b
ON 
a.seller_id = b.seller_id
AND 
a.week_end = b.week_end 
AND 
a.product_id = b.product_id;
```

Here's what I expect to happen: the query takes every existing combination of `week` + `week_end` + `year` from the table, cross joins it with every existing `product_id`, and then cross joins that result with every existing `seller_id`. While my sample table doesn't reflect this, the actual table I'm working with has rows missing, and the goal is to generate those missing rows by creating every combination of rows that already exist. For example, if seller 12345A was missing data for the week of 01/01/2020 - 01/07/2020 for a certain product, then after this operation that missing row would be created.

On to the issue: after cross-joining, I want to left join the table back onto itself to bring the `num_sold` and `dollars_sold` data back in for the rows that already existed (and whatever missing rows were generated would display a null).

After my left join, the `num_sold` and `dollars_sold` columns go missing, and I'm perplexed. I've copied the query from another table that is very similar to this one, and simply changed a few column names around. The query that I copied works exactly as stated, but when I run this modified query on this new table those two columns do not come through with the left join.

Comment: Learn what LEFT JOIN ON returns: INNER JOIN ON rows UNION ALL unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of an OUTER JOIN. After an OUTER JOIN ON, a WHERE or INNER JOIN that requires a right [sic] table column to be not NULL removes any rows extended by NULLs, ie leaves only INNER JOIN ON rows, ie "turns OUTER JOIN into INNER JOIN". You have that.

Comment: When you get a result that you don't expect/understand, stop trying to find your overall goal & find out what your misunderstanding is.--Isolate the first unexpected/misunderstood subexpression & its input & output & learn what misconception, typo, wrong reasoning, etc led to it. (Debugging fundamental.) Ask about that. When you give a [mre] give the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: @philipxy I see where the issue is. I've changed the outermost select from `SELECT a.*` to `SELECT *` and now all columns come through. I'd avoided doing this before as it was causing ambiguity errors elsewhere in my query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have created `a` to get all combinations of week/product/seller. Just selecting `a.*` ***will not display any other data*** than week/product/seller. 
You missed to include those fields (num_sold  and dollars_sold) from the left-join with alias `b`, so basically you need to add them to the main select using the `b` alias:

```
SELECT a.*, b.sum_sold, b.dollars_sold FROM 
 (SELECT     x.week_end, 
           x.week, 
           x.year, 
           y.product_id, 
           z.seller_id 
FROM       ( 
                           SELECT DISTINCT week_end, 
                                           year, 
                                           week 
                           FROM            sample_table) x 
CROSS JOIN 
           ( 
                           SELECT DISTINCT product_id 
                           FROM            sample_table) y 
CROSS JOIN 
           ( 
                           SELECT DISTINCT seller_id 
                           FROM            sample_table) z) AS a 
LEFT JOIN sample_table b ON 
a.seller_id = b.seller_id
AND 
a.week_end = b.week_end 
AND 
a.product_id = b.product_id;
```

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for, and much better than my solution of simply doing `SELECT *` in the outermost select as this avoids ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

Those columns are in the input & the result of the left join. They are not in x, y, z or the CROSS JOIN results. You can name them with or without alias b. But you aren't selecting them in your outermost SELECT clause.